# Select span for select2 using Capybara

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I'm trying to write a custom method that allows me to use our custom select2 `country_search` element. The elements are a bit wonky, but the snippet of HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="control-group select optional admins_customer_form_object_country_id">
  <label class="select optional control-label" for="admins_customer_form_object_country_id">Country</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="admins_customer_form_object_country_id" class="select optional select2-hidden-accessible" name="admins_customer_form_object[country_id]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="true">Yes</option>
      <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--classic select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 220px;">
      <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-admins_customer_form_object_country_id-container">
          <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-admins_customer_form_object_country_id-container">
            <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Select Country</span>
          </span>
          <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
            <b role="presentation"></b>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrote a helper that should select the correct `span` and perform a click on it, but I'm stuck selecting the span I want. I'm trying to select the outer visible span which has class `select2 select2-container select2-container--classic select2-container--below select2-container--focus` but I keep getting invalid XPath errors.

This is what I have so far:

```
def select_country(label:, value:)
  # Select our label first
  label_element = first("label", text: label)

  # Now navigate through the entire tree, and click the correct SPAN element.
  within(label_element) do
    select2_container = find(:xpath, "..")  # Up one level to the parent div
    select2_container = select2_container.find("div.controls")  # Down one level into the div.container
    select2_container = select2_container.find(:xpath, "./*[1]")  # select the span element surrounding all.
  end
end
```

With the last line I can select the `select` element from the tree, but I can't get the `span` sibling whatever I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly you want the span that is the child of div.controls, replacing the last two finds with the following should do that

```
select2_container = select2_container.find('div.controls > span')
```

You can add classes to the span in the css selector if needed but in your html it's the only span child so it's not necessary

Comment: thanks for this, but I've narrowed down the problem. It's not that the XPATH is invalid, the problem is that the SPAN elements are not there. For some reason the JavaScript is not being executed when the page is loaded by Capybara, even when using Poltergeist.

Comment: Check for any errors in your browsers console.  Usually in dev mode the JS files are loaded individually so an error in one doesn't stop the others from executing, however in test mode they get concatenated into one JS file which means that an error in just one of yours JS files can stop the initialization code in others from executing.

Comment: it was JS not loaded, as the tests were running under the standard Rack Runner, which does not support JS. I've rewritten the entire test setup to use Poltergheist now and it all works. Did add your line as it went a lot faster.